# Android Studio Error:Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: connection-refused

When I import a project (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) AndroidStudio shows this error:

> Error:Connection refused (Connection refused)

[image]

I've tried many things but I haven't been able to fix this error.

I'm using AndroidStudio 3.0 and Gradle 4.1. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your internet connection is on

Answer (score 3):

Set proper proxy setting if you use it, or comment out as following in the  'gradle.properties' file:

```
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=1080
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `google()` under `allProjects` and resync:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
}
```

This should resolve the issue.